# reference for slokam "udaram" on Krishna

Tags: shloka

I am trying to search the slokam that is mentioned in 34:53 in the below video

https://youtu.be/8mZCRPxDXng

I am not able to find it.

Can some one give reference for that slokam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is from the dwadasha stotra to Krishna by Madhwa

https://shivallibrahmins.com/strothras/maha-vishnu/dwaadasha-stotras-verse-by-verse-explanation/

> udaraM chiMtyaM eeshasya tanutvEπ akhilaMbaram
> valitrayAMkitaM nityaM ArUDhaM shriyaikayA || 1.4 ||

> The stomach of the Lord looks slim and small, but holds the entire Universe. It also has three lines (Vali thrayaa) and is always embraced by Ramaa (Lakshmi dEvi). Such a stomach should be contemplated.

Devanagari:

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/dvAdasha_stotra.html

> उदरं चिन्त्यं ईशस्य तनुत्वेऽपि अखिलम्भरम् ।
> वलित्रयाङ्कितं नित्यं आरूढं श्रियैकया ॥ ४॥

Comment: How did you search this? :)

Comment: Had to guess where he is making Sandhi such as "chintyameshasya" @Praphulla Koushik